# Retrieving info from multiple tables using joins in sql with cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join

My table structure is below
recipies
categories
ingredients(contain category_id)
recipies_categories
recipies_ingredients

Using **cakephp** I want to retrieve ingredients of a specified category of a specified recipe. For example I have-

recipies:recp1,recp2,recp3
categories:cat1,cat2,cat3
ingredeints:ing1,ing2,ing3
recipies_categories:recp1-cat1,recp2-cat2,recp2-cat3,recp3-cat3
ingredients_categories:ing1-cat1,ing2-cat2
Given recipe=recp2, category=cat1 or cat3 I should get no ingredients
Given recipe=recep2, category=cat2 I should get ing2

I have tried various ways using joins but couldn't get the result. Anybody can help?

Comment: show us your best attempt

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention, I have not been using raw sql statements, but doing it with cakephp. After trying I am able to get those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $settings = array();
        $settings['recursive'] = 1;
        if (!empty($selected_categories)) {
            $this->Ingredient->Behaviors->load('Containable');
            $settings['conditions'] = array(
                'Ingredient.category_id' => $selected_categories //array containing selected catagory ids
            );
            $settings['contain'] = array(
                'Category' => array('id', 'name')
            );
        }
        $settings['joins'] = array(
            array('table' => 'recipes_ingredients',
                'alias' => 'RecipesIngredient',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'RecipesIngredient.ingredient_id = Ingredient.id',
                    'RecipesIngredient.recipe_id' => $recipe_id //selected recipe
                )
            )
        );
        $this->Paginator->settings = $settings;
        $ingredients = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Ingredient);
```